# Angular 1.5 directive with one-way binding updates parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive with an isolated-scope and one-way binding variable.
yet when i change that variable in the directive controller it updates the parent scope as well.

Example code:

```
function someDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
            parentVar: '<'
        },
        templateUrl: templateUrl,
        controller: directiveController,
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    }
}

function directiveController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.$watchCollection('vm.parentVar', doSomething);

    function doSomething(newCollection) {
        var some_object = {
            property1: 1,
            property2: 2
        };

        newCollection.unshift(some_object);
    }
}
```

After I update the passed variable in the directive, I see `some_object` in other parts of my app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parentVar is an array reference, so the items that to add to it can be accessed from both parent controller.

If you do not want the changes from directive controller to be reflected, you will have to clone the array before you operate on it.

```
function directiveController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.$watchCollection('vm.parentVar', doSomething);

    function doSomething(newCollection) {
        var clonedCollection = newCollection.slice();
        var some_object = {
            property1: 1,
            property2: 2
        };

        clonedCollection.unshift(some_object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i did.  
Is this intended behavior?

Comment: Yes. '<' - one way binding ensures that watcher is not set for this variable in parent scope.